# Поиск по строкам разной длины

Tags: python, python-3.x, поиск

Имеется файл со строками, в котором нужно искать строку по введенному пользователем значению. Содержание файла такого вида:

```
45
123
0000
77788
77789
999900
```

То есть все строки различной длины. Пользователь вводит число, которое больше, чем число в БД. То есть к примеру если он введет 450, 45000123 или 45777, то должна найтись первая  строка, если введет 77788013 или 7778888, то четвертая и так далее.

Пробовал использовать функцию find(), но она ищет только по точному значению. Difflib так же мне ничем не помогла.

Есть идея перебирать посимвольно каждую строку и пользовательский ввод, там где по максимуму совпадений я узнаю длину поля в БД, потом уже этой длиной ограничить пользовательский ввод и применить функцию find(), но как это реализовать - не знаю.

Больше примеров:

```
3766
376690
3767
3768
3769
971
9712
971200
9712234
97124
97125
97126
971287
971288
```

Человек вводит число "3766823013" - находится "3766".
Вводит "3766900124" - находится "376690".
Вводит "9712473023" - находится строка "97124".
Вводит "97122348230" находится - "9712234".

Файл большой - 150 мб таких строк.

**Правильным оказался ответ:**

```
filestr.find(userstr)==0 or userstr.find(filestr)==0
```

Работает абсолютно, как надо - не отнять, ни прибавить.

Я не ввожу никого ни в какое заблуждение. Метод `find()` действительно ищет только **точное** совпадение (по крайней мере у меня он работает именно так), но стоило мне его заменить на `filestr.find(userstr)==0 or userstr.find(filestr)==0` и как по волшебству стало все работать как надо.

Comment: Читать строку из файла и регэкспом сравнивать со введенной пользователем?

Comment: А если пользователь введёт 77790 или 777905? И ещё, могут ли в бде быть строки

        77789
        777891

т.е. начало второй строки совпадает с первой?

Comment: Регэксп, думаю, что подойдет.
Если пользователь введет 77790, то четвертая, если 777905, то так же - четвертая.
Да, строки могут быть 77789 и 777891 - должно искаться до последнего совпадающего символа.

Если надо очень конкретно, то скажу, что это телефонная БД префиксов мобильных операторов. Пользователь вводит номер телефона (который по любому больше префикса) и находит строку этого префикса. Длины префикса и телефона абсолютно разные (префикс 2-6 символов, телефонный номер 7-14 символов)

Comment: Но тогда 77790 просто не соответствует ничему, ведь строка 777 отсутствует. Т.е. надо найти те строки, которые совпадают с началом проверяемой и выбрать из них наиболее длинную.

Comment: Прошу прощения, правда Ваша.
Да, именно так. Надо найти те строки, которые совпадают с началом проверяемой и выбрать из них наиболее длинную.

Comment: Так примерно (см ответ @Ilya)?

      res = ''
      for row in rows:
          if row == arg[:len(row)] and len(row) > len(res): res = row

Если у вас БД -- какая-нибудь sql'я, то запрос написать весьма несложно.

Comment: нет, просто файл txt

Comment: Тогда не забывайте про rstrip (см. ответ @Ilya), там хвостовые пробелы вполне могут быть случайно занесены при редактировании.

Comment: Для 150 мегов я бы сделал что-то вроде двоичного поиска в файле. 

Наверняка в питоне тоже можно позиционироваться на произвольный байт в файле и читать  с этого места до конца строки.

Comment: @RainRaus, странный у Вас подход **к оценке вопроса**. Я бы понял минус, за **неверный ответ**. 

Но минусовать за то то что человек что-то не понимает (ошибается) и поэтому спрашивает ???. Отпадная позиция.

Comment: Прошу извинить за то, что писал ранее. Бес попутал.

Comment: @Killer1999 мне уже ничего не нужно- я увидел свою ошибку. Я с чего-то решил, что Вам нужно не точное значение, а максимально близкое совпавшее по началу строки.  То есть из 123, 134, 135 при поиске 125 должно найти 123.  
Третье перепрочтение вопроса убедило меня в моих заблуждениях и зазря поднятом кипише.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Перебирайте построчно файл и ищите одну строку в другой и наоборот.

```
(filestr in userstr) or (userstr in filestr)
```

Или через find, тогда по началу строки сравнивать можно так:

```
filestr.find(userstr)==0 or userstr.find(filestr)==0
```

Comment: @avp Ответ, куда добавляю комментарий, не тот, но туда уже не лезет. Какие 150мег, Вы что. Если посмотрите, @Killer1999 написал: префиксы номеров мобильной связи. Это получится на каждого человека свой префикс?

Comment: @alexlz, ТС в конце вопроса добавил:

> Файл большой - 150 мб таких строк.

Если файл действительно на 150 мб, то таки да, нужно более оптимальный алгоритм реализовывать. Или бинарный поиск или хотя бы сегментировать файл, например, по первым двум цифрам.

Comment: Вот это я как-то просмотрел. Ещё и @avp писал, что файл таким быть не может. Но тогда непонятно желание возиться с txt файлом. Ну если не mysql/sqlite, то, возможно какой-нибудь berkley db... Но тут надо смотреть ТС, какой объём работы, желаемое время ответа и пр.

Comment: @alexlz, на самом деле работа с файлами при правильной (для ограниченного круга задач) организации данных всегда эффективнее, чем с СУБД. Только программа д.б. **хорошо** написана.

По поводу 150М, я думаю автор на самом деле погорячился (или у него не префиксы телефонов).

Comment: @avp "правильной", "ограниченного круга", "хорошо написана". Чем-то мне эти рассуждения напоминают сказку о высокой эффективности писанных на асме программ. Даже если и достигнут чудо-результат, то жизнь меняется, и программы тоже. А при внесении корректировок в что-то тщательно вылизанное вручную риск потерять в эффективности (несмотря на высокую стоимость работ) неотличим от 100% (невооружённым глазом). Надо будет ему сделать более оперативные корректировки (большого-то файла), или на строки ещё атрибут навесить или ещё что -- и вся стройная конструкция будет вызывать только кучу мата.

Answer (score 4):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то алгоритм примерно следующий:

```
arg = '45000123'

with open('file.dat') as fp:
    for row in fp:
        row = row.rstrip()
        if row == arg[:len(row)]:
            print(row)
```